# Auth0 login, adding local storage to manage user access

Tags: node.js, reactjs, local-storage, auth0, mern

I am constructing a demo app using the MERN Stack. I currently use auth0 to login through react, and I want to give my user special access to certain parts of the app they couldn't have prior to logging in. My question is about the correct architectural design. From what I have read, after logging in through Auth0, I should initialize some sort of session management variable  in local storage, and check for this variable across my app to restrict or enable users to certain aspects of the app.
Does this sound like the correct design or am I misinterpreting what I am reading,
and if possible, feel free to add any other suggestions on how to advance my user management/session through a MERN stack app with Auth0 authentication,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is saving the users JWT (JSON web token) inside the local storage after logging in.

If the user now sends a request to the backend API he will be authenticated with this token.

If the backend returns a 401 error, your frontend wont allow him to continue using the restricted parts of your application.

This can be realized using React Router Private Routes ([good example here)](https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e). Hope this will help you designing your auth flow.

Comment: Does the JWT come from Auth0? If not where does it originate, and how could I integrate the token to interact with the app?